# Is this expansion true for the log function? if not I will be glad to know the correct expansion of the log

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

Is this expansion true for the log function?

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEdoc.png)

I will be glad to know the correct expansion of the log(1-x)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You can start from the derivative $(\ln(1-x))'=\frac{-1}{1-x}$. In turn $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$. Therefore, integrating gives $\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{-x^{n+1}}{n+1}$. In your formula, you can see how $(-1)^{2n+1}=-1$, since $2n+1$ is odd.